# How to immediately zoom in to modal form on mobile browser

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, mobile-website

When users click on a button on my website, a Bootstrap modal form pops up. For desktop users, the size is fine (it takes up say a quarter of the page width). However, on a mobile browser, it is too small to see. When you tap on the modal form on a mobile browser, though, it will then zoom in on the form and look nice.

My question is whether it's possible to zoom in on the modal form immediately after the user taps the button (instead of having to tap the button and then tapping inside the modal form). I'd rather be able to zoom in rather than adjusting the CSS for this modal form using media queries.

Comment: Focus one of the inputs with javascript

Comment: Do you have the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` in place?